Downloading is not working using the Python requests library
I'm trying to download a PDF using the following URL, but I can't see any content. When I try different URLs, it works fine. Can someone explain what the issue might be? Does it have something to do with this website?
This is the code:
import requests

pdf_url="https://www.npci.org.in/PDF/nach/circular/2015-16/Circular_No_126.pdf"
pdf_title="test"

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0"}

response = requests.get(pdf_url, headers, stream = True)
if response.status_code==200:
    content = next(response.iter_content(10))

    with open(f"{pdf_title}.pdf", "wb") as fd:
        fd.write(response.content)


Your request is being rejected. You're not getting the document you were expecting. You're getting an HTML page that shows the error.
import requests

url = "https://www.npci.org.in/PDF/nach/circular/2015-16/Circular_No_126.pdf"
target = url.split("/")[-1]

with requests.get(url, stream=True) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    with open(target, "wb") as output:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(4096):
            output.write(chunk)

with open(target) as result:
    print(result.read())

Output:
<html><head><title>Request Rejected</title></head><body>The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.<br><br>Your support ID is: <11940751230596137624><br><br><a href='javascript:history.back();'>[Go Back]</body></html>


But if I open this link in a browser, it displays the PDF. Is it possible to use Selenium instead?

@dfcsdf selenium won't help. Use your favourite browser's dev tools to see what's going on

I observed through the browser developer tools that although the website you want to request doesn't require login, downloading the file still seems to require a cookie.
You can monitor the request headers sent when manually downloading to obtain the cookie, or you can also obtain the cookie by Application - Cookie in the browser's developer tools.
I used the following code and it was successful:
import requests

url = "https://www.npci.org.in/PDF/nach/circular/2015-16/Circular_No_126.pdf"

headers = {
    "Cookie": "TS6917...",  # Cookie, I get it from my browser developer tools, you can replace it with yours.
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/124.0.0.0",
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open("file.pdf", "wb") as f:
        f.write(response.content)
    print("Download complete!")
else:
    print("Failed to download the file. Status code:", response.status_code)

You can replace "TS6917..." with your own cookie. This script should work for downloading the PDF file.
